# How to prevent Python key listener leaks into next terminal?

Tags: python, keyboard, pynput

I have a key listener in Python to select a few options from a list. The selection works perfectly fine. However, whatever key I press will be keyed into the next terminal input. For example, here is my code

```py
import os
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

cls = lambda:os.system("cls")

def on_press(key):
    """Listen for keywords like UP, DOWN and ENTER"""
    global KEY
    if key == Key.up:
        KEY = 'up'
        return False
    elif key == Key.down:
        KEY = 'down'
        return False
    elif key == Key.enter:
        KEY = 'enter'
        return False
    elif str(key) == "'\\x03'" or key == Key.esc:
        KEY = 'esc'
        return False
    return True

def OptionSelector(option: list) -> int:
    current = 0
    while True:
        output = ''
        cls()

        for text in option:
            index = option.index(text)
            output += '(*)' if current == index else '( )'
            output += f' {text}\n'
        print(output)

        with Listener(on_press=on_press) as OptionListener:
            OptionListener.join()

        global KEY
        if KEY == 'up':
            if current > 0:
                current -= 1
        elif KEY == 'down':
            if current != (len(option) - 1):
                current += 1
        elif KEY == 'enter':
            OptionListener.stop()
            cls()
            return current
        elif KEY == 'esc':
            exit()

print(OptionSelector(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']))
```

When I press "abcdefg", nothing changes in what I see in the python code. However, the moment I press "Key.enter", the code will execute nicely then a new line from the terminal will show that I tried to execute `abcdefg` in the terminal

```sh
D:\codes\Python\data>abcdefg
'abcdefg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\codes\Python\data>
```

How do I stop the key listening from leaking into the next terminal line?

Comment: What's the `cls()`?You didn't define it.

Comment: Thanks. I just defined it. It's just to clear the terminal screen

Answer (score 0):

Using `suppress`, to stop input from entering.

Replace this line:

`with Listener(on_press=on_press) as OptionListener:`

with:

`with Listener(on_press=on_press, suppress=True) as OptionListener:`

so it suppresses all keyboard input. Be careful with this! When this happens, you can only rely on your mouse to stop the program. You might want to add a failsafe so you can stop the listener, because ctrl+c will NOT work anymore.